# itext - editable texfield is not clickable

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

I know principially how to create a editable pdf cell with itext. But in some case the editable cell could only be reached with tab key. It cannot be clicked.

What could be the reason? It seems to be associated with positioning or coordinating problems (the rectangles x/y values). But perhaps its an internal itext error.

```
public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
    if (this.enable) {
        final PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].getPdfWriter();
        final TextField textField = new TextField(writer, rectangle, String.format("text_%s", this.fieldname));
        textField.setOptions(BaseField.EDIT);
        try {
            final PdfFormField field = textField.getTextField();
            field.setFieldFlags(PdfFormField.FF_EDIT);
            writer.addAnnotation(field);
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(ioe);
        } catch (final DocumentException de) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I never received any indication whether or not my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `PdfFormField` from a `TextField`, it is interactive (editable) by default, so there's no need to set any flags. I've copied/pasted your code in a small Proof of Concept:

```
class MyCellField implements PdfPCellEvent {
    protected String fieldname;
    public MyCellField(String fieldname) {
        this.fieldname = fieldname;
    }
    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        final PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].getPdfWriter();
        final TextField textField = new TextField(writer, rectangle, fieldname);
        try {
            final PdfFormField field = textField.getTextField();
            writer.addAnnotation(field);
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(ioe);
        } catch (final DocumentException de) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
        }
    }
}
```

I've named the Proof of Concept [`CreateFormInTable`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/CreateFormInTable) and this is what I do with the cell event:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    PdfPCell cell;
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name:"));
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField("name"));
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Address"));
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField("address"));
    table.addCell(cell);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

The result is [form_in_table.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/form_in_table.pdf). As you can see from the screen shot, the fields are editable:

[image]

If this doesn't answer your question, please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem. I'm the original developer of iText. I've never seen the behavior you're talking of.